# How do I access Spotify API with new authorization requirements?

Tags: authorization, spotify

Hi: I'm trying to access generic playlists for a simple project.  Old way in JS before recent authorization requirements:

https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?type=track&q=rick+astley

Not trying to access particular account, just generic results.

How do I do a generic authorization?

Thx.

Comment: this sucks. not working for me either. now requires auth token. anyone know if this is permanent?

Answer (score 1):

You now have to go through token creation following this API https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#authorization-code-flow